# Payara Micro logging

Tags: java, payara

I run my web application with Payara with `java -jar webapp.war`

How do I set where the this Payara instance would log, for example I want to set it to `/var/log/mywebapp.log` or just relative to the Uber Jar file, what would be the command to pass?

My goal is to `tail` the logs from ssh so the log needs to have a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using from command line `java -jar payara-micro.jar --logToFile /path/file.log` or you can do it programmatically using `PayaraMicro.getInstance().setUserLogFile("/path/file.log").bootStrap();`, but I don't know if you need to use embbeded payara for do this on the main method. You can even create a logging.properties file and configure it, so you use `--logProperties logging.properties` argument when run your jar file.

Comment: You can use the programmatic method if you include Payara Micro artifact as a provided dependency in a maven project. In other words, the Payara Micro JAR needs to be on the classpath during the build stage for compiling. You don't need to add it into your application WAR as it will be already available when you start the app.